# Opening a view in Landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, landscape

I am developing an application in portrait mode.In my one view controller when I click on table view another view opened in portrait mode.I want it to be opened in landscape mode.
Please suggest me how to do this.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you solved your problem or not ????

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to achieve this is to to show the view controller as a modal with

```
[self presentModalViewController:landscapeViewController animated:YES];
```

and specify the landscape mode in

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft == interfaceOrientation;
}
```

This is because if a modal view can appear in only one orientation, the app automatically rotates to that orientation.

See the accepted answer for this question for more details: [Transitioning to landscape rotation within a uinavigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922919/transitioning-to-landscape-rotation-within-a-uinavigationcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

I think that'l do:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation: kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

Im not sure though...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cannot use `setOrientation` anymore, since it is deprecated and apps have been declined for using it.

This may be an option for you:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/33548-alternative-setorientation.html

It rotates the view using a transformation.