# iOS - How to display UILabel and UIImageView in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uilabel

I have created an UIImageView and UILabel in my AppDelegate.m file to display the title image 
My default orientation is in landscape mode but i am not able to display the image properly it shows like the below image[image: UIImage to be in landscape mode]

The desired result should be like this image given below

[image]

i also tried to rotate the image and label in my `AppDelegate.m` file this is my code
 But it dosen't display the image and title is just disappears.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[LMSFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMSFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[LMSSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMSSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[LMSThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMSThirdViewController" bundle:nil];

    UILabel *title=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 5000, 50)];
    title.text=@"Library Management System";
    [title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24]];
    [title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0]];
    title.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
    title.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);


    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5000, 50)];

    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"LMS.jpg"];
    imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);


    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
    [self.window addSubview:title];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755690/opening-a-view-in-landscape-mode

Comment: if you are adding anything to window it won't rotate automatically. you have to rotate it manually. And it's not disappearing it just getting off the screen..change it's co-ordinates and bring them back to the visible area.

Comment: so what should i do to rotate it

Comment: once see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400399/how-to-set-orientation-for-a-view-which-is-subviewed-to-window/12400868#12400868.

Comment: @Sunny it's not working in my case

Comment: Instead why can't you add TopBar to the UITabBarController and add that image to the TopBar titleView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for your response,

Instead of creating a UIImageView and UILabel in AppDelegate.m 
i had written it in my `viewController.m` file and it works properly

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
     UILabel *title=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 5000, 50)];
    title.text=@"Library Management System";
    [title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:24]];
    [title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0]];
    title.textColor=[UIColor redColor];


    UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5000, 50)];

    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"LMS.jpg"];
    [self.view addSubView:imageView];
    [self.view addSubView:title];

}
```

It automatically rotates the UIImageView and UILabel as per your orientation in iOS 6

I dont know this approach is right or not because if you want something to display in your every view of your project you should write it in you `AppDelegate.m` file 
 It not better programming you should not code it in each and every view you should implement it in `AppDelegate.m` file but in my case i am getting the result.
And i will try to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You created the view to show in the portrait mode.Hence it shows like this

When the app goes to landscape mode there are methods invoked in this process and use these methods for the reframing the views.

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559652/how-do-i-detect-the-orientation-of-the-device-on-ios)