# Push UIViewController with different orientation to previous

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

Probably a simple question, but:

My app starts (and is mostly) in portrait mode, but I have a ViewController which I need to push onto the stack which needs to open in Landscape mode.

I've searched around and found that you can't use the private API:
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

I've also found a raft of "suggested" ways of tackling it (including presenting modally instead of pushing, and pushing two instances of the ViewController)
    [Transitioning to landscape rotation within a uinavigationcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922919/transitioning-to-landscape-rotation-within-a-uinavigationcontroller)

However, I'm sure there must be an easier way to tackle this.  If anyone knows of a way to PUSH onto the stack (to preserve navigation through the tree), in such a way that the viewcontroller appears landscape, please let me know.

Thanks for all your help guys,

dunc

Comment: Why are you sure there must be an easier way? Cannyboy's answer to that question looks fairly simple to me.

Comment: Thank Roger.  You're right, Cannyboy's does work (I tried it before I wrote this post) and I'll probably end up using it.  BUT it means the status bar is hidden from that viewcontroller.  Any suggestions how I can keep it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no sense to use a `UINavigationController` push transition to present a view in a different orientation. Which way round would the navigation bar / toolbar be?

Presenting a modal view controller is the right way to go about this. If this causes the status bar to become hidden, make sure `yourModalViewController.wantsFullScreenLayout` is `NO`.