# How to customize orientation in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an application in iPhone.  In that i want first `UIViewController` opens in **Portrait** mode and second `UIViewController` opens in **Landscape** mode.

I tried this link [iOS 6: how to force change orientation when pushing view controller into the navigation controller stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370488/ios-6-how-to-force-change-orientation-when-pushing-view-controller-into-the-nav)

But it's not woking ….

Is there any solution to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib{
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation))
    {
        if ([deviceType rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location == NSNotFound) {
        }
        else{
        }
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation))
    {
        if ([deviceType rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location == NSNotFound) {
         }
        else{
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```